# Contour comparison in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, comparison, contour, canny-operator

I have create some code in opencv/c++ witch can find contour of an image (leaf)
so after getting the contour result from the method

`findContours( canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );`

the result of  this method will be saved in "contours" type  (`OutputArrayofArrays`)

so the problem is how to compare those result with an other?

I find that this method can compare but i cannot use it!

`double compare = cvMatchShapes(R, T, CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I1);`

R,T: 2 objects to compare.

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you should define what do you mean as "other" result.

Secondly, possibly it's better to use `cv::matchShapes` (C++ interface) instead of `cvMatchShapes` (C interface) - you will have less problems with types compatibility/conversion.

"contours" type from`cv::findContours` is no more than `vector<vector<cv::Point>`, i. e. there are more than one contour in its output.

`cv::matchShapes` takes `vector<cv::Point>` or `cv::Mat` as input parameters, i. e. you can compare only 2 contours with this function.

Thus you should firstly extract contours which you're interested in (for example, with more than N points, or with more than X total length) from `cv::findConntours` output, and then compare each contour to other one.

If you're interested in comparison of contours from next `cv::findContours` call output, you can do this with any matching technique for array elements (for example, brute-force, i. e. each element of previous array with each element of current array).

Some more information can be found in OpenCV documentation: [3.0 version](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html) or [2.4 version](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html).